# Proof of Lindenbaum's lemma for uncountable languages

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, order-theory

I am trying to understand [this](http://planetmath.org/lindenbaumslemma) proof of Lindenbaum's lemma for uncountable languages. *(First Proof, second proof is for countable lang)*

> Suppose Δ is consistent. Let P be the partially ordered set of all
>   consistent supersets of Δ, ordered by inclusion ⊆

My questions are:

1. What P is it?
2. Why it is possible to partially order a set of consistent supersets and how would we do it?

Comment: The highlighted text contains the answers to your question: "Let $P$ be the [thing]" means "$P$ is the [thing]," and "ordered by inclusion" means that we order $P$ by inclusion. So, what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$P$ is the set of all consistent supersets of $\Delta$, as it says.  Simply look at all supersets of $\Delta$ and reject the non-consistent ones.  There isn't really enough context in the web page for me to know where $\Delta$ comes from, but I assume there is some universal set $V$, and so we start with all subsets of $V$ that contain $\Delta$.

As for how we order $P$ it is partially ordered by $\subseteq$.  This is true of any set of sets, as I'm sure you know.

Finally, the reason to do this is to apply [Zorn's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma). You must have seen proofs like this before.  For example, the proof that every vector space has a basis.

Comment: Thank you for explanation! The real problem was that I missed the fact that 'partial' order means 'not all sets are comparable'.